# How to process a template with redirect

Tags: java, templates, servlets

I want to solve the following problem, it's about deleting entities from a database:

1. The user selects *Delete* for a certain entity
2. The is deleted from the database and disappeared from the list
3. An undo frame appears inside the page (like [Twitter Bootstrap alert messages](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#alerts)), where the user can choose to undo the deletion.

I don't know how to realize this, because at the moment I solve this that way:

- *Delete* button links to the URL: delete/entity_id
- I have written an if-case for this URL in my request handler that deletes the entity
- after the deletion is done, I send a `response.sendRedirect(/list)` so the updated list is shown

This way I cannot send additional data by redirecting it. Normally I would send the extra data by processing them via the template, but with `redirect` this is not possible.

How is such a sitation solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` methods of [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html). After all that's a way how you can pass Java objects over different HTTP requests.

In your case you could create such an Undo object and store it in the session. After the redirect you have described the session object is retrieved and its content is passed to the template.

Answer (score 2):

I have few such scenarios in my web application and here is how I solve it

I have a class called message queue which looks like following

```
public class MessageQueue {

  public static Hashtable<String, Object> messages = new Hashtable<String, Object>();

  public static void putMessage(String key, Object obj)
  {
    messages.put(key, obj);
  }

  public static Object getMessage(String key)
  {
    if(key == null)
      return null;

    Object obj = messages.get(key);

    if(obj == null)
      return null;

    messages.remove(key);

    return obj;
  }

}
```

Now this class stays in the memory. Before redirects I create some object that is needed after redirect. Create a random Guid as a String and then store this object in messagequeue

I then add this Guid as a parameter of the URL

String justDeletedId = "someId";
String guid = (new Guid()).toString();
MessageQueue.put(guid,justDeletedId);
sendRedirect("\list\?msgid=" + guid);

Now after redirect you can inspect the messageID and remove the object from the messagequeue and do whatever you please

I choose to allow using this object once ... to avoid memory leak

In the current version ... I also have implemented Last Access Eviction policy which uses a quartz job which cleans up this messagequeue periodically

Comment: +1 This seems to be a reliable solution, the only thing I am not sure is the state is creates. A web application should not be so stateful, but somewhere you have to draw the line I guess.

Comment: can you select this as an answer if it answered your question